Kubernetes Nginx Load Balancing Timeout
We’re running a React frontend and a FastAPI backend in a Kubernetes environment and are facing issues with a long-running API request. This specific API call takes about 2 minutes to complete. During this time, the frontend times out and loses its connection to the backend, causing it to automatically trigger a second API call while the first one is still running.
This creates different issues depending on our pod setup:
With a single backend pod: The frontend retries the request on the same pod, resulting in overlapping requests that add strain to the single instance.
With multiple backend pods: The frontend retries on an unoccupied pod, which starts the process from scratch on a new instance, duplicating the load.
To address the timeout issue, I’ve attempted to adjust various NGINX proxy timeouts as follows:
proxy-read-timeout: 300s
proxy-send-timeout: 300s
client-body-timeout: 300s
Despite these changes, the request is still capped at a 50-second timeout, which seems to be set globally in the NGINX configuration (nginx.conf in the Lua section). Even when I try to apply these updated timeouts using a Helm upgrade with our custom chart, the 50-second limit persists.
I'm looking for advice on two main points:
How to effectively override or increase the global timeout in the NGINX Ingress Controller to handle requests longer than 50 seconds.
Any guidance on resolving these issues or on managing extended timeouts in this setup would be greatly appreciated!
(We are looking to a Redis queuing solution for other parts of our app but for this Api endpoint might be overkill)

It might not be what you want to hear, but 2 minutes is IMO way too long for a normal HTTP request and well into the realm where you'd want a background worker, especially if the job is resource intensive. Something like Celery/Dramatic/etc. with Redis/RabbitMQ/etc. as a message queue.

Thanks for the response, we went with a celery/redis queuing system to tackle the long execution times.
